# Why my data is not arranged in a single table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

While making a table and inserting data in the table my data is not arranged inside the table the data is kept showing outside the table border and in unarranged form.

I am expecting my data in the table can be shown in arranged form where the table heading should be aligned with the matching data below the table

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Package Tracking - Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Admin Page</h1>
  <label for="packageIdAdmin">Package ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="packageIdAdmin">
  <br>
  <label for="status">Status:</label>
  <input type="text" id="status">
  <br>
  <label for="location">Location:</label>
  <input type="text" id="location">
  <br>
  <label for="estimatedDelivery">Estimated Delivery:</label>
  <input type="text" id="estimatedDelivery">
  <br>
  <button onclick="addPackage()">Add Package</button>
  <br><br>
  <h2>List of Saved Packages</h2>
  <button onclick="viewPackageList()">View Package List</button>
  <div id="packageList"></div>

  <script src="admin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the javascript codes

```
// Function to store package data
function storePackage(packageId, status, location, estimatedDelivery) {
    const packageData = {
      status: status,
      location: location,
      estimatedDelivery: estimatedDelivery
    };
    localStorage.setItem(packageId, JSON.stringify(packageData));
  }
  
  // Function to retrieve package data
  function retrievePackage(packageId) {
    const storedPackage = localStorage.getItem(packageId);
    return storedPackage ? JSON.parse(storedPackage) : null;
  }
  
  // Function to add package by admin
  function addPackage() {
    const packageId = document.getElementById("packageIdAdmin").value.trim();
    const status = document.getElementById("status").value.trim();
    const location = document.getElementById("location").value.trim();
    const estimatedDelivery = document.getElementById("estimatedDelivery").value.trim();
  
    if (packageId && status && location && estimatedDelivery) {
      storePackage(packageId, status, location, estimatedDelivery);
      alert("Package added successfully!");
    } else {
      alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    }
  }
  
  // Function to view list of saved packages by admin
  function viewPackageList() {
    const packageListDiv = document.getElementById("packageList");
    packageListDiv.innerHTML = "";
  
    packageListDiv.innerHTML += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Package ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Location</th><th>Estimated Delivery</th></tr>";
  
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      const packageId = localStorage.key(i);
      const packageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(packageId));
  
      packageListDiv.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
          <td>${packageId}</td>
          <td>${packageData.status}</td>
          <td>${packageData.location}</td>
          <td>${packageData.estimatedDelivery}</td>
          <br>
        </tr>
      `;
    }
  
    packageListDiv.innerHTML += "</table>";
  }
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Read more on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You can start by providing some snippets of your code.

Comment: It looks as though the table isn’t structured properly with table and tr and td tags used correctly. Please show us the relevant HTML and any associated CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added snippets of the codes can you help with it

Comment: Please provide the HTML as requested, not an image of (part of) the code that generates it. Please read the link we have given, it is provided to help you give us what we need to help you.

Comment: Please, please show the resultant HTML or at least a minimal reproducible example - we don’t know how these functions are called.

Comment: You can use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what code has been produced. Please do this.

Comment: I have done what you told sir but I cannot find the solution

Comment: I asked that the resultant HTML be put into the question - that is, I'd like to see what HTML has been produced by your code. You can see the relevant HTML in your browser devtools inspect facility. Is there some problem with doing this?

Comment: OK, I ran a boiled-down version of your code and found the resultant HTML for myself. What is happening is that the system is closing the table for you when you load the heading line into the innerHTML (to ensure there are not unclosed tags). Instead you could build up the innerHTML in a JS variable , str, and then only when it is complete put it into the DOM (the innerHTML). Also, you have a spurious br tag in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you put HTML into innerHTML the system adds closing tags.

You can see this by using your browser devtools inspect facility.

Hence you are ending up with more than one table.

A simple way of preventing this automatic closure is to make a string of all the HTML and then copy the string into the innerHTML.

Here is the code (it cannot be a snippet as the snippet system does not allow access to local storage.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Package Tracking - Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Admin Page</h1>
  <label for="packageIdAdmin">Package ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="packageIdAdmin">
  <br>
  <label for="status">Status:</label>
  <input type="text" id="status">
  <br>
  <label for="location">Location:</label>
  <input type="text" id="location">
  <br>
  <label for="estimatedDelivery">Estimated Delivery:</label>
  <input type="text" id="estimatedDelivery">
  <br>
  <button onclick="addPackage()">Add Package</button>
  <br><br>
  <h2>List of Saved Packages</h2>
  <button onclick="viewPackageList()">View Package List</button>
  <div id="packageList"></div>
<script>

// Function to store package data
function storePackage(packageId, status, location, estimatedDelivery) {
    const packageData = {
      status: status,
      location: location,
      estimatedDelivery: estimatedDelivery
    };
    localStorage.setItem(packageId, JSON.stringify(packageData));
  }
  
  // Function to retrieve package data
  function retrievePackage(packageId) {
    const storedPackage = localStorage.getItem(packageId);
    return storedPackage ? JSON.parse(storedPackage) : null;
  }
  
  // Function to add package by admin
  function addPackage() {
    const packageId = document.getElementById("packageIdAdmin").value.trim();
    const status = document.getElementById("status").value.trim();
    const location = document.getElementById("location").value.trim();
    const estimatedDelivery = document.getElementById("estimatedDelivery").value.trim();
  
    if (packageId && status && location && estimatedDelivery) {
      storePackage(packageId, status, location, estimatedDelivery);
      alert("Package added successfully!");
    } else {
      alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    }
  }
  
  // Function to view list of saved packages by admin
  function viewPackageList() {
    const packageListDiv = document.getElementById("packageList");
    let str = "";
  
    str += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Package ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Location</th><th>Estimated Delivery</th></tr>";

    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      const packageId = localStorage.key(i);
      const packageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(packageId));
      str += `
        <tr>
          <td>${packageId}</td>
          <td>${packageData.status}</td>
          <td>${packageData.location}</td>
          <td>${packageData.estimatedDelivery}</td>
          <br>
        </tr>
      `;
    }
  
    str += "</table>";
    packageListDiv.innerHTML = str;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a snippet to show it works (with data in the code rather than from local storage).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Package Tracking - Admin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Admin Page</h1>
  <h2>List of Saved Packages</h2>
  <button onclick="viewPackageList()">View Package List</button>
  <div id="packageList"></div>
  <script>
    // Function to view list of saved packages by admin
    function viewPackageList() {
      const packageListDiv = document.getElementById("packageList");
      let str = "";

      str += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Package ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Location</th><th>Estimated Delivery</th></tr>";
      str += `
        <tr>
          <td>ID1</td>
          <td>READY</td>
          <td>NEW YORK</td>
          <td>1 APRIL</td>
        </tr>
      `;
      str += "</table>";
      packageListDiv.innerHTML = str;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```